# How to plot 3 lines against each other and auto-adjust the scale

Tags: matlab

The biggest issue here is auto-adjusting the scale.  I have 4 data vectors: 3 representing data collected (to be plotted on the y-axis) and one representing the x-axis values.

I want to plot these 3 lines against each other.  But also, their values tend to be very small (maxing out around 0.1 most of the time).  The default is a plot from 0 to 1.  How do I make that auto-adjust?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what's [plot](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/plot.html) itself doing wrong? it (I think always) adjusts the scale automatically

```
x=0:10;
y1 = x/100;
y2 = log(x)/25;
y3 = 0.4./x;
y = [y1 ; y2 ; y3];
plot(x,y);
```

As you can see in the following picture [image]

this plots here on my computer with xlim = [0 10] and ylim = [0 0.4], which is equal to the span of respectively vector x and matrix y.

If the axes are still not as you like them, you can set them yourself with

```
xlim([minx maxx]);
ylim([miny maxy]);
```

possibly in combination with [min](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/min.html) and [max](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/max.html) functions on the data x(:) and y(:) as follows:

```
xlim([min(x(:)) max(x(:))]);
ylim([min(y(:)) max(y(:))]);
```